# Is there a way to determine in what way an app has been closed on Android?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I installed a native app (an APK) on an rooted Android device. When I do dome specific action the app unexpectedly closes, but tombstore_NN file is not crated in /data/tombstones folder so I do not save a stack trace and I have no idea on what has happened.

Is there a way to determine in what way the app closes? (Add some hook like SetUnhandledExceptionFiler on Windows, etc...).

I do not have the source code of the app, but I have C++ source code of a library (.so) that is injected into this app and that supposedly causes this. I tried to add some logging into this library, and then see them with

```
adb logcat
```

but the line where the logs end varies from run to run (a few last lines are not shown) so I can't determine the exact point where the code stops executing.

Comment: On Android 11 and later there's [`getHistoricalProcessExitReasons`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager#getHistoricalProcessExitReasons(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int))

Comment: @Michael should I call this from Java code? Is there a way to get this info from the command line with `adb`, for example?